# mysql : json type : construction of a groupby query

Tags: mysql, json, group-by

I need to group json elements across db rows

the query I am using is :

select JSON_EXTRACT(m.content,'$.m.tags[*].wrd') as word, count(*) as    count from m group by word order by count desc

the result I get is

```
["#utmp", "#seasiders"] 5
["embeddedurl", "#IMDb", "#nowwatching"]    4 
["YouTube", "embeddedurl"]  4 
["#seasiders", "embeddedurl"]   4
```

I need individual word / tokens :

```
["Thanks"]  3 
["seriously"]   2 
["#doh"]    2
```